# Is there a workaround for method reportFullyDrawn()?

Tags: android

I'm trying to measure app launch time and the documented `reportFullyDrawn()` is the solution that reports the timing I'm looking for.

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/launch-time.html

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#reportFullyDrawn()

It turns out that on `runtime`, the `reportFullyDrawn()` method throws the exception

```
"java.lang.SecurityException: uid 10156 does not have android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS".
```

Also, the application doesn't automatically report the launch time as a  "`Displayed`" line in the log (as it should, if I'm not mistaken).

I didn't find this issue mentioned anywhere. Did this happen to someone else? Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: For anyone curious, this exception does not happen after KitKat 4.4 (according to Cyril Mottier) so is not a problem if minSdkVersion >= 21

Comment: You also get a SecurityException when in in a managed profile (android for work). This is observed at least on Samsung devices with Android 6-9, thus it seems like a good idea to always call reportFullyDrawn() within a try-catch-block.

Comment: @mattlaabs yes, I also experience this on Android 6-9. Thanks for the heads-up that this is related to Android for work.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to catch the Exception. The method works but unfortunately it throws a `SecurityException`. There is no way to fix it.

Here in this presentation it mentions the same problem with an elegant solution. https://speakerdeck.com/cyrilmottier/launch-screens-from-a-tap-to-your-app

Just like how `Compat` classes in Android support library, he wraps the fix into a static method in a `Compat` class to encapsulate the ugly try/catch.